# toolbars beside each other

Tags: java, swing

I want to place two separate toolbars at top of JFrame and be able to move each one alone to the east,west,or south of the frame, i tried to use BorderLayout ,but that does not help, i know that i can put each one at panel with BorderLayout and be able to move them around ,but what i acutally need is to put them beside each other ,and be able to move around each one alone,this code does not work but it would help with understand my question,please can any one help me ?

```
package test;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class testform extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public testform() {
        initComponents();
        jPanel1.removeAll();
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        MultiBorderLayout amMultiBorderLayout = new MultiBorderLayout(0, 0);
        jPanel1.add("North", jToolBar1);
        jPanel1.add("North", jToolBar2);
        jPanel1.add("Center",jPanel2);
        jPanel1.setLayout(amMultiBorderLayout);

        jPanel1.revalidate();

    }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jToolBar1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jToolBar2 = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 156, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(43, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(71, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jToolBar1.setRollover(true);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.setFocusable(false);
    jButton1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jButton1.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jToolBar1.add(jButton1);

    jToolBar2.setRollover(true);

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.setFocusable(false);
    jButton2.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jButton2.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jToolBar2.add(jButton2);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                    .addComponent(jToolBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToolBar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 63, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jToolBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jToolBar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 103, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 104, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new testform().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JToolBar jToolBar1;
private javax.swing.JToolBar jToolBar2;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented the BorderLayout extension to support this.
UPD: The same code with a small test app http://java-sl.com/tip_multiple_floatable_toolbars.html

Use it instead of BorderLayout here `jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Extends BorderLayout with multiple components in the northList, southList, eastList, westList
 * and centerList. Layout is used for correct working multiple toolbars.
 *
 * @author    Stanislav Lapitsky
 * @version   1.0
 */
public class MultiBorderLayout extends BorderLayout {

    /**
     * list of the northList region components
     */
    Vector northList = new Vector();

    /**
     * list of the southList region components
     */
    Vector southList = new Vector();

    /**
     * list of the westList region components
     */
    Vector westList = new Vector();

    /**
     * list of the eastList region components
     */
    Vector eastList = new Vector();

    /**
     * list of the centerList region components
     */
    Vector centerList = new Vector();

    /**
     * Constructs default layout instance.
     */
    public MultiBorderLayout() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs new layout instance with defined parameters.
     *
     * @param hgap  the horizontal gap.
     * @param vgap  the vertical gap.
     */
    public MultiBorderLayout(int hgap, int vgap) {
        super(hgap, vgap);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified component to the layout, using the specified
     * constraint object. For border layouts, the constraint must be one of the
     * following constants: <code>NORTH</code>, <code>SOUTH</code>, <code>EAST</code>
     * , <code>WEST</code>, or <code>CENTER</code>. <p>
     *
     * Most applications do not call this method directly. This method is called
     * when a component is added to a container using the <code>Container.add</code>
     * method with the same argument types.
     *
     * @param name         The feature to be added to the LayoutComponent
     *      attribute.
     * @param comp         the component to be added.
     */

    //the method is deprecated but it's necessary to override it because current class extends
    //BorderLayout to provide multiple components (toolbars) 
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        synchronized (comp.getTreeLock()) {
            /*
             *  Special case:  treat null the same as "Center".
             */
            if (name == null) {
                name = "Center";
            }

            /*
             *  Assign the component to one of the known regions of the layout.
             */
            if ("Center".equals(name)) {
                centerList.add(comp);
            } else if ("North".equals(name)) {
                northList.insertElementAt(comp, 0);
            } else if ("South".equals(name)) {
                southList.add(comp);
            } else if ("East".equals(name)) {
                eastList.add(comp);
            } else if ("West".equals(name)) {
                westList.add(comp);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: " + name);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified component from this border layout. This method is
     * called when a container calls its <code>remove</code> or <code>removeAll</code>
     * methods. Most applications do not call this method directly.
     *
     * @param comp  the component to be removed.
     */
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        synchronized (comp.getTreeLock()) {
            southList.remove(comp);
            northList.remove(comp);
            centerList.remove(comp);
            westList.remove(comp);
            eastList.remove(comp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines the minimum size of the <code>target</code> container using
     * this layout manager. <p>
     *
     * This method is called when a container calls its <code>getMinimumSize</code>
     * method. Most applications do not call this method directly.
     *
     * @param target  the container in which to do the layout.
     * @return        the minimum dimensions needed to lay out the subcomponents
     *      of the specified container.
     */
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
        synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);

            Component c;

            if (eastList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < eastList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) eastList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getMinimumSize();
                    dim.width += d.width + this.getHgap();
                    dim.height = Math.max(d.height, dim.height);
                }
            }
            if (westList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < westList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) westList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getMinimumSize();
                    dim.width += d.width + this.getHgap();
                    dim.height = Math.max(d.height, dim.height);
                }
            }
            if (centerList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < centerList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) centerList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getMinimumSize();
                    dim.width += d.width;
                    dim.height = Math.max(d.height, dim.height);
                }
            }
            if (northList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < northList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) northList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getMinimumSize();
                    dim.width = Math.max(d.width, dim.width);
                    dim.height += d.height + this.getVgap();
                }
            }
            if (southList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < southList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) southList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getMinimumSize();
                    dim.width = Math.max(d.width, dim.width);
                    dim.height += d.height + this.getVgap();
                }
            }

            Insets insets = target.getInsets();
            dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;

            return dim;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines the preferred size of the <code>target</code> container using
     * this layout manager, based on the components in the container. <p>
     *
     * Most applications do not call this method directly. This method is called
     * when a container calls its <code>getPreferredSize</code> method.
     *
     * @param target  the container in which to do the layout.
     * @return        the preferred dimensions to lay out the subcomponents of
     *      the specified container.
     */
    public Dimension prefferedLayoutSize(Container target) {
        synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);

            Component c;

            if (eastList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < eastList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) eastList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    dim.width += d.width + this.getHgap();
                    dim.height = Math.max(d.height, dim.height);
                }
            }
            if (westList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < westList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) westList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    dim.width += d.width + this.getHgap();
                    dim.height = Math.max(d.height, dim.height);
                }
            }
            if (centerList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < centerList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) centerList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    dim.width += d.width;
                    dim.height = Math.max(d.height, dim.height);
                }
            }
            if (northList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < northList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) northList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    dim.width = Math.max(d.width, dim.width);
                    dim.height += d.height + this.getVgap();
                }
            }
            if (southList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < southList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) southList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    dim.width = Math.max(d.width, dim.width);
                    dim.height += d.height + this.getVgap();
                }
            }

            Insets insets = target.getInsets();
            dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;

            return dim;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lays out the container argument using this border layout. <p>
     *
     * This method actually reshapes the components in the specified container
     * in order to satisfy the constraints of this <code>BorderLayout</code>
     * object. The <code>NORTH</code> and <code>SOUTH</code> components, if any,
     * are placed at the top and bottom of the container, respectively. The
     * <code>WEST</code> and <code>EAST</code> components are then placed on the
     * left and right, respectively. Finally, the <code>CENTER</code> object is
     * placed in any remaining space in the middle. <p>
     *
     * Most applications do not call this method directly. This method is called
     * when a container calls its <code>doLayout</code> method.
     *
     * @param target  the container in which to do the layout.
     */
    public void layoutContainer(Container target) {
        synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
            Insets insets = target.getInsets();
            int top = insets.top;
            int bottom = target.getHeight() - insets.bottom;
            int left = insets.left;
            int right = target.getWidth() - insets.right;

            Component c;

            if (northList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < northList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) northList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    c.setSize(right - left, d.height);
                    c.setBounds(left, top, right - left, c.getHeight());
                    top += d.height;
                }
            }
            if (southList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < southList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) southList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    c.setSize(right - left, d.height);
                    c.setBounds(left, bottom - d.height, right - left, c.getHeight());
                    bottom -= d.height;
                }
            }
            if (eastList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < eastList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) eastList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    c.setSize(d.width, bottom - top);
                    c.setBounds(right - d.width, top, c.getWidth(), bottom - top);
                    right -= d.width;
                }
            }
            if (westList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < westList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) westList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    c.setSize(d.width, bottom - top);
                    c.setBounds(left, top, c.getWidth(), bottom - top);
                    left += d.width;
                }
            }
            if (centerList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < centerList.size(); i++) {
                    c = (Component) centerList.get(i);
                    if (!c.isVisible()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    c.setBounds(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thnx for your answer .i create this class and edit my code to use it like this , but i got emprty frame  
public testform() {  
        initComponents();   
        jPanel1.removeAll();  
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));  
        MultiBorderLayout amMultiBorderLayout = new MultiBorderLayout(0, 0);  
        jPanel1.setLayout(amMultiBorderLayout);  
        amMultiBorderLayout.addLayoutComponent("North", jToolBar1);  
        amMultiBorderLayout.addLayoutComponent("North", jToolBar2);  
        jPanel1.revalidate();  
        
    }

Comment: Add components to container not to layout.

Comment: yes that work thnx , but the moving of each toolbar to another side ,like drag first toolbar to west and the second to east not working

Comment: i have edit my code again ,and now the moving is working good , but still there small issue , with first run the two toolbars placed beside each other , but after i drag one of them to the west for example ,and then return it to the north ,it placed at under the first toolbar not beside it

Comment: Incorrect order. You first add component and then set layout. For me the drag works fine (tried) your code.